# Proving a function (on metric space) is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

[image]

Hello everyone,
I am struggling with this question. I have to prove the above question in both questions. One of the main problems I am having in proving continuity is which definition of continuity is best used to prove the statement.  I know several definitions of continuity:

1. For any e>0, there exists a delta(e,p)>0: f(B(p, delta)) is a subset of B'(f(p),e).

or in other words 
[image]

2. f: M-->N is (globally continuous) iff $f^-1$(A) is open in M for any open subset A in N.
3. Continuity in terms of sequences: 
   [image]

My thinking for this question was to use the second definition.

I was thinking of showing that the pre-images of the sets $f(x)<c$, $f(x)>c$  are open in order to show continuity.

However, I'm not sure if this is the correct method nor do I know how to show the pre-images of said sets $f(x)<c$, $f(x)>c$ are open.  Note, I know nothing about compactness, I only know these three definitions.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea.
Assume $f$ is cont on $M$, that is for any open set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}$, the pre- image of $E$ is open in $M$. We can fix arbitrary $c \in \mathbb{R}$, choose an open set $\{y|y<C\}$, so the pre-image of this set under $f$ would be $\{x|f(x)<c\}$.

For the converse part, assume both sets you provided are open in $M$ for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and assume arbitrary open set $E \in \mathbb{R}$, we know any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the arbitrary union or finite intersection of the following open intervals, namely $(a, \infty)$, $(-\infty, a)$ and $(a,b)$. In that case, you can deduce that the pre-image of set $E$ is open in $M$, hence we can show $f$ is cont on $M$.

Hopefully, this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if this is the correct method

Your direction is right.

> how to show the pre-images of said sets $f(x)<c$, $f(x)>c$ are open.

This is already given in the problem.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure where it is given in the problem that the pre-images are open?  Thanks.

Comment: @kemb "Prove that $f$ is continuous on $M$ *if* and only if *the sets $\{x:f(x)<c\}$  and $\{x:f(x)>c\}$ are open in $M$ for every $c\in\Bbb R$*".